# How to edit a _root function in Flash Pro CS 5.5

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I need to create a global function in a .fla file. I understand I should put it in `_root`.

I'm having trouble finding how to edit `_root` in Flash Pro CS 5.5.

Sorry by the naive question.

Comment: how to add a global function?

Comment: global methods should be avoided at all costs.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, please be more clear about your intentions so we can better assist you. What will the function do and why does it need to be global (it doesn't, and shouldn't, but why do you want it to be?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad idea, global functions pollute the global scope, make for unextendable and unscalable code that does not play nice with other code.

That said, inn actionscript 2 the following should work:

```
_root.myFunctionName = function(){
    trace("do whatever here");
    //your actions
};

// you can now call _root.myFunctionName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding your function (or a variable) to a script attached to the main timeline will create it in the `_root` scope and make it accessible anywhere in your program via the `_root` keyword.

You should note that it's generally considered good practice to avoid calls to root if possible. The main reason is that the scope will change if your movie is loaded into another movie since root will then refer to the parent movie.